# Looping through generated HTML with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know if I wanted to bind events to generated HTML, I'd need to use something like `.on()`, but I've only used it when binding events like `.click().`

I'm creating a web app that applys a list of colors. Colors are generated from a JSON file. Once fetched, I add it to the page, with certain information contained in attributes. I'd like to do something with the new generated HTML, which is list-elements. But what `console.log()` is showing me is there is nothing in the parent `ul`. Even though on the page I see the newly added content.

Here's the entire code based around it.

```
var setColors = function(){

    getColors = function(){
        $.getJSON('js/colors.json', function(colors) {
                $.each(colors, function(i, colors) {
                //console.log(colors);
                    $('<li>', {
                        text: colors['color'],
                        'name' : colors['color'],
                        'data-hex' : colors['hex'],
                        'data-var' : colors['var']
                    }).appendTo('#picker');
                })
        });

        addColors();
    }

    addColors = function(){
        var el = $('#picker').children;
        $(el).each(function(){
            console.log($(this));
        });
    }

    return getColors();
}


$(function(){

    setColors();

});
```

addColors() is where I'm having trouble with.  The error says 'Uncaught `TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild'` of null. How can I work with the newly generated HTML?

Answer (score 3):

You are missing parentheses on the children method:

```
var el = $('#picker').children();
```

Also, if you want the addColor method to be executed on the newly generated html, then you must add a call to it after the html is generated, from within the `getJSON` callback method.

Comment: And console.log() doesn't return anything now.

Comment: is that because when addColors is called there isn't any children? Keep in mind that you are appending html via ajax so the newly generated html isn't there when the method is executed

Answer (score 0):

```
addColors = function(){
    var el = $('#picker').children;
    $(el).each(function(){
        console.log($(this));
    });
}
```

A few issues:

1. missing end semi-color
2. missing parentheses on `.children()`
3. children() returns a jQuery object, no need for `$(el)`

Updated:

```
window.addColors = function(){
    var $el = $('#picker').children();
    $el.each(function(){
        // do stuff here, but could attach each() to above, after children()
    });
};
```